# invoke an integer and double in JFrame.JTextField().setText();

Tags: java, swing

I just learn a ORM with MVC. I make a class.

```
public bookController {

private static final Connection Connection = null;
    JFramebookstore frameBookstore;
    Bookimpl bookimpl;
    List<book> listbook;

// and i just add a function to show a books that choose from JTableBooks

public void showfield(int row) {
   frameBookstore.JtextBookid().setText(listbook().get(row).getBookId().toString());
frameBookstore.JtextSellingprice().setText(listbook().get(row).getsellprice().toString());
  }
}
```

I have an error to invoke getBookid()and getbooksellprice()

This is my Constructor class

```
public class book {

private int bookid;
private double booksellprice;

public final int getBookid() {
        return bookid;
    }
    public final void setBookid(int bookid) {
        this.bookid = bookid;
    }

public final double getBooksellprice() {
        return booksellprice;
    }
    public final void setBooksellprice(int booksellprice) {
        this.booksellprice= bookselprice;
    }

public book(int bookid, double booksellprice){

   super();
   this.bookid = bookid;
   this.booksellprice = booksellprice;
  }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "book [bookid=" + bookid + ", booksellprice=" +booksellprice+"]
 }
}
```

I have read the [tutorial String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) but still I cannot solve my own self.

this is my bookTable model extends AbstractTableModel

```
 public class bookTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

 list<book> books;

public bookTableModel(List<book> books) {
    this.books = books;


@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return books.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
    switch (column) {
    case 0:
        return "bookid";
    case 1:
        return "booksellprice";
    default :
        return null;

    }

}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    switch (column) {
    case 0:
        return books.get(row).getbookid();
    case 1:
        return books.get(row).getbooksellprice();
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
 }
}
```

this is my bookDAO class implement bookimpl

```
'@Override
public class BookDAO implements bookimpl {
private final String select = "SELECT * FROM DSCM.BookData ";

public List<book> getByAll() t{
    List<book> books = null;


    try {
        books = new ArrayList<book>();
        Statement statement =  connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(select);


        while (result.next()) {
            book b = new book();

            b.setbookid(result.getInt("bookid"));
            b.setbookid(result.getDouble("booksellprice"));


            books.add(book);
        }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return books;  

 }
}'
```

and this is my bookimpl class

```
public interface bookimpl {

public void insertbook(Book b) throws Dascomerror;

public void updatebook(book b) throws Dascomerror;

public void deletebook(int bookid) throws Dascomerror;

public List<book> getByAll() throws Dascomerror;

'
```

the error its says

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dascom.dao.bookDAO.getByAll(bookDAO.java:138)
at com.dascom.controller.bookController.<init>(bookController.java:38)
at com.dascom.view.JFramebook.<init>(JFramebook.java:136)
```

Comment: `listbook().get(row)` ?

Comment: Don't use the `<>` button above the message posting/editing form for Java code samples!  It is only for HTML/JS that can be run in a browser.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  *"I have an error to invoke getBookid()and getbooksellprice()"*  **What** error exactly?  Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: > listbook().get(row). thats in my AbstaractTableModel

>

Comment: then where is the code?

Comment: You forgot to capitalize the `i` in `getBookId` when you declared it (`public final int getBookid()`). Change `getBookid` to `getBookId` in your `book` class. Same for the setter. You declared it as `getBookid`, but call it like `getBookId`. Since you forgot to capitalize, it doesn't notice the method and tells you it doesn't exist

Comment: wait i will write it. 

i just learn how to write and ask in the stackover flow

Comment: For future reference, note that a [mcve] requires you to 'coagulate' all the classes into a single source code.  As it stands, the person trying to test the code above would need to define 6 classes and do 6 copy/paste/compile actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused with variables and functions it seems. No need for `()`when accessing varibles

```
frameBookstore.JtextBookid().setText(listbook().get(row).getBookId().toString());//wrong

frameBookstore.JtextBookid.setText(listbook.get(row).getBookId().toString());//right way
```

and you can't dereference `int` and `double` I mean `.toString()` is not available for primitive types like `int`,`double`

Go with `String.valueOf()`

```
frameBookstore.JtextBookid.setText(String.valueOf(listbook.get(row).getBookId()));
```

And those function names are different in `getBookId()` and `getBookid()` seems like typo
`getsellprice()` and `getBooksellprice()`

Comment: thanks Madhan. it solve. 

when u say to delete the bracket in Jtextbookid. its says its not visible.

Comment: @AgungTuanany Make `Jtextbookid` public in `JFrameStore`

Comment: allready i make all the JText  and Jtable all in public now i get some error in java.lang.null.pointer at bookDAO.getByAll().

and i can't make some a question more in new question stackoverflow.

Comment: Sir Madhan may i ask u more simple question.

cause i cant more ask more new question on stackoverflow.

now i get an error with java.lang,NullPointerException bookDAO.getByALL.

this is my bookDAO simple code. up in my main question

Comment: @AgungTuanany you haven't initialized `connection` inside  `getByAll` function